# Book(s ?) about Succubi in England

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Roughly a year ago I have read a book about a Succubus in current day London. Basically she was a human that transformed to a Succubus in the night and when she transformed it was as if another version of herself took over control over her actions. As a Succubus she could fly and had a magical way to influence men that slowly drove them into madness.

There were other Succubi in the story and for some reason they were trying to convince the protagonist to become an ally. I think she was supposed to be very powerful once she mastered her powers.

In contrast to the other existing Succubi she was reluctant to use her powers, because as a teenager, when she realized her transformation she started to hurt people in her vicinity. Therefore she built herself some sort of cage by electrifying the lock on her home at the time of her transformation with no way to turn it off so that her other self couldn't escape.

Being able to turn into a Succubus runs in the family, though her mother was left out. Her grandmother gave her some pills that would help with the transformation, though she can only take them at a certain time. Otherwise they would amplify her need to transform instead of suppressing it. Her grandmother died and she finds a stash of the pills at the house of a few older neighbours. I think the grandmother lived in Germany when she was still alive.

The protagonist probably killed parts of her family when she was in Succubus form. I think her sister died and later her parents in an accident. But she can't remember what exactly happened.

It felt mostly like an introduction, which is why I feel it was the first book of a series. I've read it in German. The book was quite new when I read it.

Random things I still remember:

- she had a cat
- making breakfast for herself and the cat consisting of porridge was described quite often
- later the protagonist gets a cage in her attic in addition to the electric door - I think she uses this to show someone she likes in which way she transforms in the night
- the book starts with a different Succubus convincing a man to jump from a roof and thereby killing himself to show his love for her

I can't remember what the book was called and I wanted to have another look at the series. Can you help me remember the name of the series?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *Nachtmahr: Das Erwachen der Königin* from [Ulrike Schweikert](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrike_Schweikert)

After some more googling and thinking about this book I finally found the name. The title could roughly be translated to *Nightmare: The awakening of the Queen* and is only available in German. The translation sounds wrong, because *Nachtmahr* is an old word for a creature of the night, so you should read this as *night-[mare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_(folklore))*, which, according to Wikipedia, is often similar to a succubus or incubus. There is no Wikipedia page for the book or the series as a whole and the one from the author I linked in the header of this answer is only available in German.

The word *succubus* was therefore in a way wrong, because the author used the older word *night-mare* and the most common occurence in modern literature that I am aware of would call such a creature a *succubus*.

Here is the German blurb from the back of the book, which I will try to translate as best as I can:

> Sie ist schön, sie ist verführerisch – sie ist das gefährlichste Wesen der Nacht
>
> Tagsüber ist Lorena eine unscheinbare, junge Frau – aber jede Nacht verwandelt sie sich in ein wunderschönes Wesen, getrieben von unbändiger Lust: Sie ist ein Nachtmahr. Kein Mann kann ihr widerstehen, und wer einmal ihren Reizen erlegen ist, verfällt ihr auf ewig. Aber dann trifft sie auf Jason, ihre große Liebe. Ihm zuliebe versucht Lorena verzweifelt, den zerstörerischen Nachtmahr in ihr zu bändigen. Lorena ahnt jedoch nicht, dass sie ihr wahres Wesen nicht verleugnen kann. Denn sie ist die Auserwählte, die über das Schicksal der Nachtmahre entscheiden wird ...

My attempt at a translation:

> She is beautiful, she is seductive - she is the most dangerous creature of the night
>
> By day Lorena is an unremarkable, young woman - but every night she transforms into a wonderfully beautiful creature, driven by uncontrollable lust: she is a nightmare. No man can resist, and who succumbed to her charm once is addicted forever. But then she meets Jason, her great love. For him she desperately tries to control the destructive nightmare inside of her. Lorena however does not anticipate that she cannot deny her true nature. For she is the chosen one, to decide the fate of the nightmares...

The other books in the series are:

- *Die Schwester der Königin* (*The sister of the Queen*)
- *Das Vermächtnis der Königin* (*The legacy of the Queen*)

Comment: Sounds a bit closer to a "night hag", which was associated with the same phenomenon as with incubi, back when they were horrific monsters and not seducers (TL;DR, "night terrors" which happen when you wake up in the wrong phase of sleep and can't move due to sleep paralysis, which tends to feel like someone is sitting on your chest and is often associated with a strong feeling of something staring at you). :) Just saying that that might be a closer match for the translation, other than that they used the modern sexy version.